# Google App script without log in to google account

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently started working on google app script. I've add a script with my google spreadsheet. that script runs on loading of spreadsheet.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  //This function loads an HTML form on loading of spreadsheet.
  showForm();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Show Form', 'showForm')
  .addToUi();

}
```

But when I am sharing this spreadsheet with email account other than gmail, Script dosen't execute.

Do I need to login with google account in order to run this script ?

Comment: The `onOpen()` function is calling another function named `showForm();`  Maybe the `showForm()` function has code in it that needs to know the Google account?  You need to add error handling to your code.  You stated that the script doesn't execute, but it is probably executing, but failing.  Those are two different things.  You need to know what line of code it is failing on.  Comment out `//showForm()` and see if the menu shows up.  If it does, then the code is executing, and the problem is in the `showForm()` code, which you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most scripts can't run if the user is not logged into their Google account on a computer. The `createMenu()` method can't run without the user logged in.